# Поиск совпадений с помощью regexp и запись в файл

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Всех приветствую.

Необходимо извлечь все айпи адреса из строки с помощью regexp и записать в файл. Но, массив, полученный с помощью regexp принимает неудобный вид, как можно переделать данный код, чтобы записывались все айпи адреса?

```
            $string = "127.0.0.1:8000 127.0.0.1:81 127.0.0.1:77 127.0.0.1:66";
            preg_match_all("/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5})/", $string, $result);
            $res = '';
            foreach($result as $key => $value) {
                $res .= $value[$key]."\r\n";
            }
            file_put_contents('text.txt', $res);
```

(Записываются только первые 2 айпи адреса)

var_dump:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(14) "127.0.0.1:8000" [1]=> string(12) "127.0.0.1:81" [2]=> string(12) "127.0.0.1:77" [3]=> string(12) "127.0.0.1:66" } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(14) "127.0.0.1:8000" [1]=> string(12) "127.0.0.1:81" [2]=> string(12) "127.0.0.1:77" [3]=> string(12) "127.0.0.1:66" } }
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не надо использовать регулярные выражения где попало, ваша задача прекрасно решается через `explode`. Код на [`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/gozxCe);
2. У вас пишется в файл содержимое переменной `$res`, но если подняться по коду чуть выше - она у вас обнулена и ничем не заполняется.

Comment: @ua6xh, благодарю. Но мне было бы интересно, как можно преобразовать данный массив и записать содержимое? + тут может быть такая ситуация: TEXT127.0.0.1:80TEXT, explode не поможет...

Comment: @evansive 
1. У вас представлена ситуация не `TEXT127.0.0.1:80TEXT`, а `\sIP\s`, мы тут не экстрасенсы.
2. Сделайте `print_r($result);` после `preg_match_all` и посмотрите что у вас там. Там массив из 2-х элементов, 1-й это то, где была найдена строка, 2-й это то что попало в поисковую группировку в регулярном выражении. Вам надо просматривать второй массив в цикле. `foreach($result[1] as $key => $value) {...someCode...}`

Comment: @ua6xh, спасибо, что объяснили, как распределяются данные в этом массиве, теперь все понял.